# Horizontal scroll bar in shiny in inactive state

Tags: r, shiny, scrollbar

In shiny app numeric input widgets are created dynamically in row and column which i want to put in a box with horizontal scroll bar if more than 2 columns are selected.

Scroll bars appeared both at top and bottom but in inactive state.I have tried with auto option in scroll but not working. Please help.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(title = "scroll bar in inactive state"), 
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(numericInput("rows","Input No. of rows",value = 5,min=1),
             br(),
             numericInput("col","Input No. of cols",value = 1,min=1)),


mainPanel(box(title = "what if", 
                              width = 7,
                              style = "overflow-x: scroll", uiOutput("plo")))
)))
```

server.R

```
 server <- function(input,output){

 # creating input widgets dynamically
 output$plo <- renderUI({
 z <- input$col

lapply(seq(input$col), function(j){
  column(width=5,
         lapply(seq(input$rows),function(i){
           numericInput(inputId = paste0("range",paste0(i,j)),label =  
     j,value = paste0(i,j))  
         })
  )
 })
})
}
```

Comment: I think it's primarily because of the width of your textInput, since it's already small maybe the scroll isn't active.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

`div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', uiOutput("plo"))` instead of 
style = "overflow-x: scroll", uiOutput("plo")

Comment: Nup....horizontal scroll bar still inactive even more columns are selected